# Javascript bootstrap dropdown menu isn't working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site I'm working on and am using bootstrap. I want to have a dropdown menu in the navbar but the dropdown tab in the nav doesn't respond when clicked. I searched previous questions about this and made sure that

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

comes before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

which seemed to be the most common issue. I also have all the files in one folder so the issue isn't there either.

Eventually I just set up a new site with only the nav bar to figure out what was going on. I think the problem is with invoking jQuery or javascript. All the code for the nav bar is straight from bootstrap.

In my head I have:

```
<head>

<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
```

The body is just the navbar code as copied directly from bootstrap. The navbar shows up correctly.

Why is the dropdown not responding when clicked?

Comment: jQuery 3.0 and up isn't currently supported: you can check this out for more info on jQuery dependency. [bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json).

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the issue by swapping out
     <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

with

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>